# Prevent specific computer names from attempting to authenticate. +

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have 2 users that are repeatedly getting locked out of the domain by a couple of computers that are repeatedly trying to login to their Exchange Accounts.   The story is, these 2 users were using some sort of service to mine leads or something, and that service had access to their accounts.   They cancelled this service awhile ago, and have since changed their passwords.   They have contacted the company but they seem to be dragging their feet with getting this issue fixed.

So my question is, if I know the names of the machines that causing the lockouts by repeatedly trying to access their Exchange accounts, is there a way to block those computer names?

These computers (i assume they are computers) are external. I am getting the names from the security logs. We have no machines with those names on our domain.

Thanks

Comment: If the authentication requests are coming from the computers that sort of implies that there's a service or application running on those computers that is generating the requests, so why not uninstall the service or application?

Comment: Those computers (i assume they are computers) are external. I am getting the names from the security logs. We have no machines with those names on our domain. Am I making sense?

Comment: Sorry, I am the OP, I thought I was logged in when I posted.

Comment: Block those connections at your network firewall.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in Active Directory or Windows Server 2008R2?   I don't have access to our firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Firewall.

Go to `Inbound Rule`

Create New Rule

`Rule Type:`  Custom
`Program:`  All Programs
`Protocol Type:` Any
`Which local IP address does this rule apply to`  These IP Addresses and add the IP in.  If it's a remote IP do it under remote IP.

`Action:`  Block connection
`When does rule apply:`  Check all
`Name & Description`:  Self explanatory
Click Finish.